# How to modify LocalizedResourceName in such a way to prevent Windows from changing it?

Tags: windows, localization, windows-shell

I hate the English localized shell names in Windows 7. I much prefer how Vista had it. I hate have "My " preappended to a handful of directories, which are obviously mine. They exist under my user profile. The name of the directories are correct, but explorer changes what they are by the LocalizedResourceName key in the desktop.ini file, which lives in the directory. When I get a new user account setup I go through each desktop.ini file and delete the LocalizedResourceName key. I would be fine with this solution, except occasionally a Windows update will be "helpful" and will put the LocalizedResourceName key back into the desktop.ini file. 
I imagine the solution is to change the LocalizedResourceName to some value which means "Ignore me and just use the directories actual name on disk". And when when the update runs it'll see that the LocalizedResourceName key is there and won't modify it.
So, does LocalizedResourceName have a special value which means "just use the name on the disk"?
Or am I going to have to write a script which will run during boot which deletes all instances of LocalizedResourceName?

Comment: An interesting question, but not really programming. Voting to move to superuser.com. Good luck.